# How to change the numerical value of a variable after it has already been defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do you change the value of a variable after it has already been defined, and then next time you run the program, have the variable changed to the new value.

```
p = 0
result = int(input("Test "))
if result == 3:
   points = p+3
   p = points
```

Basically, I need it so that next time I run this code, "p" has been set to 3, and then the time after that, it changes to 6, as so on.

Comment: You can output the value of your variable to a file. Read the file at start of program and write to file at end of program.

Comment: Are you familiar with reading and writing files?

Comment: Or databases? You need some kind of persistent (probably on-disk) storage.

Comment: You could also use the `pickle` module and create a .pickle file that saves the variable's value. I consider this to be slightly cleaner than using a .txt file to do so.

Comment: I believe you have a fundamental misunderstanding how how computer programs work. When you load up the Python interpreter and execute a Python program, the program's objects are created in [*main memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage#Primary_storage), i.e. RAM.  What you are looking for is [data persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)), which is generally achieved by writing your data in some format to *auxiliary memory*, i.e. writing to disk.

Comment: This can be a simple text file that you parse manually (because the data will always be loaded as strings), or you can use one of the various standard serialization formats, like JSON using the `json` library, or pickle's for binary storage of arbitrary python objects (using the `pickle` library).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

with open('tmp.txt', 'r') as file:
     p = file.read()
os.remove("tmp.txt")
result = int(input("Test "))
if result == 3:
   points = int(p)+3
   p = points
   with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as file:
       file.write(str(p))
```

Try this out. Create a file "tmp.txt" in the same folder as your code before running the script.